# Найти совпадающие элементы двух массивов в разных ячейках двух массивов

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Я делаю программу. Мне надо найти не совпадающие элементы массива, но только не вот так вот:

```
arr1[i] == arr2[i]
```

А в разных ячейках совпадение. например чтоб найти совпадение в таких массивах:

```
{5, 5, 2, 2} {2, 2, 5, 5}
```

Как можно это реализовать? Я не смогла это реализовать

Comment: Если кратко и просто, не претендуя на полноценный ответ: Использовать 2 вложенных цикла по `i` и по  `j` и получится `arr1[i] == arr2[j]`. Пробовали? В более продвинутом варианте сортировка еще может помочь, чтобы избежать квадратичной сложности, но в таком случае все равно использовать 2 счетчика надо.

Comment: как вариант можно отсортировать, а потом сравнить

Comment: Самое простое решение, как заметили выше, – в двух циклах обойти оба массива. А дальше зависит от задачи (условий и требований): скажем, обязательно ли полностью хранить массивы? Если у Вас очень ограниченное множество, можно завести счетчики элементов. Да и вообще формулировка задачи противоречивая – то ли совпадающие, то ли не совпадающие элементы.

Comment: @Marionette, и получить сложность задачи O(N^2), Danis как раз наиболее оптимальный вариант сказал - отсортировать и сравнивать и отделаться O(NlogN)

Comment: @Zhihar, разумеется, могу ошибаться, но, кажется, такой вариант и пригоден, и эффективен для этой задачи (исходя из примера). Поправьте, если заблуждаюсь. https://ideone.com/TeURK1

Comment: Уточните условие, приведя примеры входных/выходных данных

Comment: @Алена Ваш вопрос не понятен. Вы пишите: "Мне надо найти НЕ совпадающие элементы массивов" И тут же пишите : "Найти СОВПАДЕНИЯ в разных ячейках массива". Переформулируйте задачу, у Вас в вопросе два диаметрально противоположных условия..